# Bring x back to the center inequality

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

[image]

[image]

What is the process behind this? i know multiply by x is the first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have \begin{alignat*}{2} x\left(\frac{4}{7}-\epsilon\right) < 4 &\Rightarrow x &&< \frac{4}{\frac{4}{7}-\epsilon} \qquad \text{(assuming $\epsilon < \frac{4}{7}$)} \\ & &&= \frac{7(4)}{7\left(\frac{4}{7}-\epsilon\right)} \\ & &&= \frac{28}{4-7\epsilon}\end{alignat*} and similarly \begin{equation*}x\left(\frac{4}{7}+\epsilon\right) > 4 \Rightarrow x > \frac{28}{4+7\epsilon}\end{equation*} Combining these yields \begin{equation*}\frac{28}{4+7\epsilon} < x < \frac{28}{4-7\epsilon}\end{equation*} as stated.

Comment: Ah, i get it now
Is there a name and shortcut for this "maneuver" of bringing the x back into the middle

Comment: There's not really a specific name for it. It's just solving the inequalities for $x$.